# Declare as property OR pass as method arguments

Tags: php

I am writing a MySQL class.I notice that this cosfuses me already.I need to passing for example the table as an argument to a function or declare a property and do a setter method first before executing.

```
public $table;
public function fetchByUniqueId($table,$id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM etc";
}
```

Comment: Properties are mostly used when you have a variable you want to use in multiple methods, i dont think this is the case with the $table, rather pass it as a parameter to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->fetchByUniqueId()` method has a hard dependency on `$table`; if you make it available via the `->table` property, you're hiding that dependency which makes your code "smell".

The best is to, as much as possible, define all direct dependencies in the method signature.

An exception to this would be if `$table` is made a dependency of the class constructor and then it shouldn't change throughout the lifetime of the instances created from it.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way.  Is `$table` something that tells you about the particular instance of your MySQL class or data that a function would need in order to perform its operation?

Also which makes the code easier to understand?  In your case, passing in the table name as a parameter is more explicit as to what is needed than setting it to a property of the class.

Properties should help define particular details about the instance of the object.  It tells what an object 'is' or what an object 'has'.  The `MySql` class that you are creating does not represent one particular table so it should not be a property of that class.